# A box have $20$ light bulb, and we know $5$ are faulty. find the probability of function, and the expected value of get 3 fulty light bulb. (random)

Tags: probability

A box have $20$ light bulb, and we know $5$ are faulty. find the probability of function, and the expected value of get 3 fulty light bulb. (random)

**My work**

Let $X=0,1,2,3$
Let $p:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a function such that

$p(X=0)=\frac{\binom{5}{0}\binom{15}{3}}{\binom{20}{3}}$
$p(X=1)=\frac{\binom{5}{1}\binom{15}{2}}{\binom{20}{3}}$
$p(X=2)=\frac{\binom{5}{2}\binom{15}{1}}{\binom{20}{3}}$
$p(X=3)=\frac{\binom{5}{3}\binom{15}{0}}{\binom{20}{3}}$

Well, for find is only apply the definition

$E[X]=\sum_{x\in X}xp(x)$

My question, is good the probability function?

Comment: How many bulbs are you picking in total along with $3$ defective bulbs?

Comment: I only can pick 3 bulbs. then i can get 1 defective bulb, 2 or 3 defective bulbs. @tienlee, i cannot pick 4 bulbs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your probability is correct.
$n(s)=\binom{20}{3}$, since we are choosing $3$ bulbs from $20$ bulbs.

When there are $3$ defective bulbs in selection then the probability is 
$$\frac{\binom {5}{3}\binom{15}{0}}{\binom{20}{3}}$$
When there are $2$ defective bulbs in selection then the probability is 
$$\frac{\binom {5}{2}\binom{15}{1}}{\binom{20}{3}}$$
When there are $1$ defective bulbs in selection then the probability is 
$$\frac{\binom {5}{1}\binom{15}{2}}{\binom{20}{3}}$$
When there are $0$ defective bulbs in selection then the probability is 
$$\frac{\binom {5}{0}\binom{15}{3}}{\binom{20}{3}}$$

Comment: Thanks for that, very glad for take the time in see my question!